The exact nuance of “淫乱”
I'm seeing somewhat different definitions of “淫乱” floating around, JMDict gives:

debauched; lewd; lascivious; lecherous; salacious; wild

Japanese Wiktionary gives:

淫らな行為に耽りやすいこと。その人。女性に用いることが多い。

These two mostly seem to suggest the meaning is about the nature of the sexual acts one partakes in. Implying one can be both “淫乱” and strictly monogamous provided one's sexual tastes are sufficiently wild or unusual. However several Hinative answers give something along the lines of

いろいろな人と性交渉をしている人のことです。

This implies it's more so about the volume space of the persons one has sexual intercourse, not the nature of the intercourse itself. Implying one can be both “淫乱” but purely partake in fairly standard and conventional sexual acts, provided it be with a sufficiently large enough pool of individuals.
So which of both is it, or can it mean either?

Technically, the dictionary definition is correct. One can be described as 淫乱 even if they have only one partner or if they're still a virgin. That being said, indiscriminately seeking sexual partners is the most representative manifestation of being 淫乱, so HiNative's comment is not entirely wrong.
On the other hand, vulgar words like this and this explicitly mean they readily engage in physical relationships, and this concept has little to do with sexual perverseness.
